# Powershell http api call

Tags: powershell, api

I want  to make a Http call with powerscript, over non secure connection, because I dont have any ssl certificate on my local server. I have tried to use `-AllowUnencryptedAuthentication` But it response with the parameter doesnt exist. Do I have to update powershell? I currently use version `5.1.18362.1171` of powershell

Here is my script:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication $url
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1#parameters): _"This feature was added in PowerShell 6.0.0."_

Comment: you can add the script from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187634/powershell-invoke-restmethod-using-self-signed-certificates-and-basic-authentica which will then ignore the cert

Comment: I just read, but thanks... But found out it actually works without in ps 5, I just havn't started my asp.net yet.. So yeahhh. But thanks for quick relpy <3